# Definite Integral by Bernoulli numbers

Tags: numerical-methods

How we can show the following definite integral on $[0,1]$?

$\begin{eqnarray}‎
‎ \int _0^1\left(\ln \frac{x}{1-x}\right)^kdx=(2^k-2)\pi ^k|B_k|,
‎\end{eqnarray}‎$

where $B_k$ are the $k$-th Bernoulli numbers, $k=1,2,\ldots$, respectively.

Note that the Bernoulli numbers $B_k$'s are a sequence of signed rational numbers. For every odd $k$ other than $1$, $B_k=0$. For every even $k$ other than $0$, $B_k$ is negative if $k$ is divisible by $4$ and positive otherwise. The first few Bernoulli numbers for $k=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10$ are

$B_k=1,-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{6}, 0,-\frac{1}{30},0,\frac{1}{42},0,-\frac{1}{30},0,\frac{5}{66}$.

Answer (score 1):

Performing the change of integration variable $\frac{x}{{1 - x}} = e^{t}$ from $x$ to $t$ turns your integral into
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{ + \infty } {\frac{{t^k e^t }}{{(e^t  + 1)^2 }}dt} .
$$
If $k$ is positive and even, the integrand is even. Hence, by http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.5.E4 and http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.6.E2, we find
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{ + \infty } {\frac{{t^k e^t }}{{(e^t  + 1)^2 }}dt} = 2\int_{0}^{ + \infty } {\frac{{t^k e^t }}{{(e^t  + 1)^2 }}dt} = 2(1 - 2^{1 - k} )k!\zeta (k) = (2^k-2)\pi^k |B_k|.
$$
For positive odd $k$, the integrand is an odd function, whence the integral is $0$. Thus your claim is indeed true for all positive integer $k$.